# help with a php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array that looks like this,

```
    Array
(
    [email_address] => Array
        (
            [0] => sadasdasd
            [1] => Simosdsad
        )

    [firstname] => Array
        (
            [0] => sadsadas
            [1] => simon
        )

    [surname] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdasdasdasdasd
            [1] => ainley
        )

    [companies_company_id] => 
    [save_user] => Save User
)
```

all the keys [0] are related is there away to make these there own array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be something like this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)  {
    $newArray[] = $value[0];
}
```

Is there a reason you haven't?

Comment: @sico87 Sure.  Most welcome.  There's probably a way to do it using array handling functions.  But that's the most straightforward.